# Single HTTP request for HTML template file for multiple instances of the same Web Component

Tags: javascript, templates, web-component

Say I have a Web Component defined like this:

```
// web-component.js
export class WebComponent extends HTMLElement {
  template = '/path/to/template.html';  
  tmpl = {};

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
    
  async connectedCallback() {
    const html = fetch(this.template).then(response => response.text());
    this.doSomething(await html);
  }
  
  doSomething(html) {
    console.log(html);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', customElements.define('web-component', WebComponent));
```

A template file like this:

```
//template.html
<template id="web-component">
    <h1>Text Goes Here</h1>
</template>
```

And a web page like this:

```
//index.html
    ....
    <head>
    <script type="module" src="/path/to/web-component.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <web-component>Foo</web-component>
    <web-component>Bar</web-component>
    <web-component>Baz</web-component>
    </body>
    ....
```

The web browser is making three http requests to fetch the same template file. I want to store the html from the template file somewhere on the client so I'm only making a single http request.

I tried this:

```
async connectedCallback() {
  const existing_template = document.body.querySelector('#web-component');
  console.log(existing_template);
  if (existing_template) {
    this.doSomething(existing_template);
  } else {
    const html = fetch(this.template).then(response => response.text());
    this.addTemplateToWebPage(await html);
    this.doSomething(await html);
}

addTemplateToWebPage(html) {
    const tag = document.createElement('body');
    tag.innerHTML = html;
    document.body.appendChild(tag.querySelector('template'));
}
```

But existing_template is always null, so I'm still making unnecessary http requests. I also tried this, with the same result:

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.doSomething();
  }

  async doSomething() {
    const existing_template = document.body.querySelector('#web-component');
    console.log(existing_template);
    if (existing_template) {
      this.doSomethingElse(existing_template);
    } else {
      const html = fetch(this.template).then(response => response.text());
      this.addTemplateToWebPage(await html);
      this.doSomethingElse(await html);
    }
  }

  doSomethingElse(html) {
    console.log('doing something else');
  }
```

How can I do this so I only have a single http request when calling the same template?

Comment: At first look all 3 ``<web-component>`` are parsed and upgraded **before** that ``<template>`` is filled with cached content; I don't think using the DOM as cache is the best option here.

Comment: @Danny That makes sense.  How would you approach the problem?

Comment: You inspired me to add caching to my [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) Took some _**serious**_ tweaking. See my work in progress at: https://load-file.github.io/ Key (IMHO) is to store the cache on the Class itself and then use a **second** Web Component that actually displays the content, because that way all existing (but still :undefined) components and all future components will display the correct cached content.

Comment: @Danny Thanks for sharing that. I never would have thought to approach it that way. Will play around with the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a static class property, initialized as FALSE
- In the class constructor, check the value of the static property and, if needed, fetch the template file.
- In the constructor, set the value of the static property with the result of the fetch.
- Flag the connectedCallback method as async and use AWAIT to retrieve the
  static class property.
- Clone the template to use in the instance(s).

my-component.js

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static file = '/path/to/template.html';
  static template = false;

  constructor() {
    super();
    if (!MyComponent.template) {
      MyComponent.template = MyComponent.fetchTemplate();
    }
  }

  async connectedCallback() {
    const tmpl = await MyComponent.template;
    this.tmpl = tmpl.cloneNode(true);
    console.log(this.tmpl);
  }

  static async fetchTemplate() {
    return await fetch (MyComponent.file)
    .then (response => response.text())
    .then (txt => {
      const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(txt);
      return frag.querySelector('template').content;
    });
  }
}
```

template.html

```
<template id="my-component">
    <h1>Text Goes Here</h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing to the HTML isn't clear, but an easy way is to create a custom fetch wrapper for your HTML template. Something like this:

```js
const fetchTemplate = (() => {
  const cache = new Map();
  return async (path, options) => {
    if(cache.has(path)) return cache.get(path);
    const res = await fetch(path, options);
    const data = await res.text();
    cache.set(path, data);
    return data;
  };
})();
```

This presents a much more streamlined approach and can be easily adapted for other templates.

**Usage:**

```js
async connectedCallback() {
  const html = await fetchTemplate(this.template);
  this.doSomething(html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried placing your custom fetch wrapper inside the connectedCallback function, I saved it as a separate export and imported it into my class, and I modified it to be a regular class method and, while in all three cases the template file is imported, I'm still making three http requests for it. Where should I place the fetch wrapper?

Comment: @HomeSlice I'm a bit confused regarding your description. Anyways, I would put the `fetchTemplate` outside of any function or class, and call it inside the `connectedCallback` method as suggested. By the way, I just tested it and know for a certain that the `fetchTemplate` function works as expected.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something stupid. I just tried putting the fetchTemplate function inside a script tag in my main web page (index.html), and called it from inside the connectedCallback method, but it's still making three http requests. Before each time fetchTemplate is called, the cache.size is 0 and after each time, cache.size is 1. I'm assuming that before the second and third invocations of fetchTemplate, cache.size should be 1, but it's not. The Map is getting reset. I even moved the cache variable [cache = new Map()] into it's own script tag, but it's still not keeping the entry.

Comment: @HomeSlice hmm... could you send a sandbox link to reproduce the link?

Comment: Here's a link to a sandbox: https://plnkr.co/edit/D6UGEBBqWSUKfvKW?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: @HomeSlice ahh, I figured it out. First, you're sending a request to `./template.html`, which is relative to the HTML page, not what JS file you're in, so you need to do something like `./lib/template.html`. Besides that, there's a flaw in my fetch wrapper that indeed causes the request to be sent 3 times: the fetch wrapper is called all at the same time, so at the time the map doesn't have anything added. I'll edit my answer with a suitable wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original question refers to an "HTML" template, I'm not sure if, technically, this really answers it, but it has been a few days so I will relate how I solved my problem. Basically I just changed template.html to template.js, turned the template html code into a javascript literal, and export/imported it into my class. I guess the browser automatically caches the http request because it's only making a single http call. I didn't transpile or use any build tools ... it just worked in the most recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Edge (which is all I'm concerned about). It has been awhile since I have played with this stuff and I'm kinda blown away at the current browser support for vanilla javasript modules. When we finally get HTML imports that play nice with javascript modules, I'm hoping this approach makes it easy to refactor the code to accommodate the new technology.

My file structure is:

```
/www
- index.html
- /components
-- /my-component
--- component.js
--- template.js
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="/components/my-component/component.js">  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-component>One</my-component>
        <my-component>Two</my-component>
        <my-component>Three</my-component>
    </body>
</html>
```

template.js

```
export const template = `
<template id="my-template">
    <style>
        h1 { color: dimgray }
    </style>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Need Text</h1>
    </div>
</template>
`;
```

component.js

```
import { template } from './template.js';
export class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  shadow = {};
  tmpl = {};
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
   }
   
   connectedCallback() {
    this.setVars();
    this.build();
    this.render();
   }
   
   setVars() {
    const tmpl = this.setTemplate(template);
    this.tmpl = tmpl.querySelector('template').content;
   }
   
   setTemplate(html) {
     const range = document.createRange();
     return range.createContextualFragment(html);
   }
   
   build() {
    // do something 
   }
   
   render() {
    this.innerHTML = "";
    this.shadow.append(this.tmpl);
   }
  }
   
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent));
```